# Find the column name of last not null value in a row

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table is like this

```
ID A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7   A8   A9
1  YE  YE    YE  NULL  YE   YE   YE  NULL NULL
2  YE  YE    YE  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
3  YE  YE    YE   YE   YE    YE   YE  YE  NULL
```

Where ID is the primary key.
I want to fetch the column name of last not null value in a row, Result is like this

```
ID LAST
1   A7
2   A3
3   A8
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Can I say "that schema looks awful"? :-) It can be done with a reverse-priority conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Despite my misgivings about this schema, consider this "reverse-priority" conditional:

```
select
  id,
  case
    -- first match terminates search
    when A9 is not null then 'A9'
    when A8 is not null then 'A8'
    when A7 is not null then 'A7'
    ..
    else null
  as lastNonNullColumn
from ..
```

The order of evaluation is guaranteed in TSQL (see [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)) so we just inchworm backwards :)

> Evaluates, in the order specified, Boolean_expression for each WHEN clause.

Also, perhaps [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) ( or `ROLLUP`[?] or manual `UNION`) could be used. That is, pivot the fixed set of column names into values, then it's a simple query .. that is, if the table was normalized, this could be done easily :-)

```
select
  id,
  max(colName) as lastNonNullColumn
from <<normalized_derived_table>>
where colValue is not null
group by id
```

Comment: Your CASE expression has the best execution plan and takes the least CPU. UNPIVOT operations require a costly SORT

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  It uses an `UNPIVOT` to transform the data and then you will select the max last value's that are not null/blank.

```
;with cte as
(
  select id
    , last
    , value
    , row_number() over(partition by id order by last) rn
  from
  (
      select id, 
          isnull(a1, '') as a1, 
          isnull(a2, '') as a2, 
          isnull(a3, '') as a3, 
          isnull(a4, '') as a4, 
          isnull(a5, '') as a5, 
          isnull(a6, '') as a6, 
          isnull(a7, '') as a7, 
          isnull(a8, '') as a8, 
          isnull(a9, '') as a9
      from t
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
      value
      for last in (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9)
  ) u
) 
select id, max(last) as last
from cte
where value != ''
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7562/8)

Edit, actually it doesn't need to be that complicated:

```
select id
  , max(last) last
from
(
    select id, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9
    from t
) x
unpivot
(
    value
    for last in (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9)
) u
group by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7562/12)

Comment: Both your versions work but require the column names to be sortable (including not having A10 and up). I'm pretty sure the OP's columns aren't actually named A1 - A9.

Comment: @ErikE true, but based on the requirements that were posted, this will work.  If they expanded on their needs that would be helpful.  The OP states the table included columns a1-a9.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudo-UNPIVOT version that lets you specify the order of the columns (if the column names do not sort by their position).

```
SELECT
   T.ID,
   X.Name
FROM
   T
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM (
         VALUES (1, 'A1', T.A1), (2, 'A2', T.A2), (3, 'A3', T.A3), (4, 'A4', T.A4),
         (5, 'A5', T.A5), (6, 'A6', T.A6), (7, 'A7', T.A7), (8, 'A8', T.A8),
         (9, 'A9', T.A9)
      ) X (Pos, Name, Col)
      WHERE Col IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY X.Pos DESC
   ) X;
```

However, while actual IO and CPU are not much worse than the natural UNPIVOT method (the execution plan looks bad, but the real server impact is not that much worse), this is not the best performer. The simple CASE expression given by @pst is.

Assuming the column names *can* be sorted as is, the UNPIVOT can be simplified even more:

```
SELECT ID, Max(Last)
FROM T UNPIVOT (Value FOR Last IN (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9)) U
GROUP BY ID;
```

Finally, here's a crazy version I thought of that unfortunately performs worse than the others:

```
SELECT
   T.ID,
   Coalesce(
      (SELECT 'A9' WHERE T.A9 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A8' WHERE T.A8 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A7' WHERE T.A7 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A6' WHERE T.A6 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A5' WHERE T.A5 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A4' WHERE T.A4 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A3' WHERE T.A3 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A2' WHERE T.A2 IS NOT NULL),
      (SELECT 'A1' WHERE T.A1 IS NOT NULL)
   ) LastNotNullColumn
FROM T
ORDER BY ID
```

Theoretically, the engine could come up with a plan that looks a lot more like the CASE expression version, but it doesn't. The plan looks absolutely crazy, with one table object per select statement, and takes about twice CPU as the CASE expression.

All versions I tested use the same number of logical reads, only varying in the CPU. I used 15,000 rows to test.

Last, I can't in good conscience not warn you that your schema is probably not best. While I can't tell what your data is, that you're trying to find the last one probably suggests the columns represent time or stages of some life cycle--and that is not correct database design. Instead, store the data unpivoted. When the time comes that you need a result set that is pivoted, you can PIVOT. And, querying for the most recent value per ID becomes a bit simpler!